# Overriding virtual member function containing constant

Tags: c++, overriding, constants, virtual, member-functions

How can I override a virtual member function of the following type:

```
virtual AnimalId func(int index) const
```

where `AnimalId` is a `typedef` `unsigned int`

I tried several ways but either ending up by an error that I don't give output or that I don't have an overrider at all. I saw on some website that maybe I need to use static const in order to do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: what do you want to override? the returned value? the type of the returned value?

Comment: Could you show what you tried and what the error was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override method of signature

```
virtual AnimalId func(int index) const
```

declared in base class `Base`, you have to define function with same signature in derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
   virtual AnimalId func(int index) const
     {
         return 43;  // I am using 43 because I think this is
                     // so much underestimated in favor of 42
     }
    //...
};
```

Or you can type `override` kryword to be more explicit:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
   virtual AnimalId func(int index) const override
     {
         return 43 & 45;
     }
    //...
};
```

Comment: thanks 43 worked :D I thought I tried the same before when I was getting LNK2001 error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like: (Note, you have to remove `override` if you compile for C++03)

```
typedef unsigned int AnimalId;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual AnimalId func(int index) const { return 0; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    AnimalId func(int index) const override { return 42; }
};
```

Comment: thanks it worked. I thought I tried the same before when I was getting LNK2001 error.